# modernizr check for grayscale filters IE 10

Tags: jquery, filter, modernizr

IE 10 does not support DX filters (yeaaaay) I'm currently using `$.browser` to detect IE 10 and implement the svg solution.

However the `$.browser` is deprecated and will be removed or is already removed (Yeaaaay again!!!!). So, what is modernizr's alternative for `$.browser` in this case?

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+ */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
-webkit-transition: all .6s ease; /* Fade to color for Chrome and Safari */
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Fix for transition flickering */
```

I tried `if (Modernizr.css_filters)` but that didn't work

Comment: But I'm not asking for gradients! And the grayscale filter is not supported on IE 10, believe me....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
Modernizr.cssfilters
```

or

```
Modernizr.svgfilters
```

For targeting IE10 I think `.svgfilters` is the one you should be using. Here's a searchable database of Modernizr tests: http://www.browserleaks.com/modernizr#filter

These are the source files:

CSS Filter test: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/filters.js

SVG Filter test: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/svg/filters.js